# Изменение записей в таблице по дате и времени PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql9.6

Перед мной возникла задача хранения информации о классе учеников школы. На данный момент эта информация хранится в виде даты зачисления в первый класс и литеры.

Я решил написать триггер, который будет при добавлении ученика фиксировать его класс исходя из этой даны и времени или наоборот, который будет высчитывать дату зачисления в первый класс и литеру из строки класса. Но ученики переходят из класса в класс каждый год, соответственно в БД нужно фиксировать изменение класса каждый год 1-го сентября, например.

**Отсюда вопрос:** можно ли вносить изменения в БД по определенной дате? Если да, то как?
И не менее важный вопрос, стоит ли это делать? Или подобными вычислениями принято нагружать API?

Comment: Надо сделать структуру БД таковой, что бы этого не требовалось делать. Например таблица привязки учеников к классам может выглядеть: id-ученика, id-класса (или другая инфа о нем), дата начала, дата окончания. Когда ученик поступает в школу и идет привязка к классу создается запись с нужной датой начала, а в дату окончания ставится скажем 01.01.3000. Если ученика переводят в другой класс или он уходит из школы дата окончания ставится на день выбытия и при переводе создается новая запись с нужной датой начала. Это позволит фиксировать изменения не только 1 сентября, но в любой день

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. У меня есть только дата начала обучения, сколько оставался на второй год и флаг о том выпустился ли ученик, стоит его поменять на дату выпуска, а так я полностью с вами согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал как сказал @Mike в комментарии

> Надо сделать структуру БД таковой, что бы этого не требовалось делать.
>   Например таблица привязки учеников к классам может выглядеть:
>   id-ученика, id-класса (или другая инфа о нем), дата начала, дата
>   окончания. Когда ученик поступает в школу и идет привязка к классу
>   создается запись с нужной датой начала, а в дату окончания ставится
>   скажем 01.01.3000. Если ученика переводят в другой класс или он уходит
>   из школы дата окончания ставится на день выбытия и при переводе
>   создается новая запись с нужной датой начала. Это позволит фиксировать
>   изменения не только 1 сентября, но в любой день

Использую в таблице дату начала обучения, дату окончания обучения, сколько раз оставался на второй год и букву класса. В принципе этого достаточно, чтобы определить актуальный класс.